# spell check screen in Mail MacBookPro

Tags: email

Why does the spell check screen in Mail pop up everytime I write an email and does not underline misspelled words? I cannot turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to "Preferences" and select "Composing" make sure that "Check spelling" is set to "as I type" rather than "when I send".

This should fix it.